# Is there a way to download and store Google Maps permanently?

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

Google Maps are arguably the most accurate online maps in the world, but the problem is that the app itself has many limitations when it comes to offline use like not allowing downloads of maps bigger than a certain size and deletion of stored maps after a number of days.

Is there a way within Google Maps or using 3rd party software (available on F-Droid maybe) that can download Google Maps and store them indefinitely and also allow offline search? Or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: It would be really cool if there was a database+Xposed mod out there that you could launch on your device that would mimic Google's server and feed the info straight into the app.

Answer (score 3):

I use [MAPS.ME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro) as an alternative. It works perfectly offline, you can save places, search anything in the downloaded maps, and it has a router for driving and walking too. Its map data is from [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org). It is also accurate enough, (but) it can be edited by anyone, though this *can* lead to mistakes (I've not encountered any of them so far), and on the other hand, sometimes it is even more detailed than Google Maps.

Anyway there are a lot of apps on Google Play using OSM's data.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Google Maps 9.22.1 allows downloading multiple offline areas. Offline directions & voice navigation is also supported. You can download areas up to max 120,000 sq km. Maps are updated after 30 days.

[Google Support - Download and Use Offline Areas](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6291838?hl=en)

Comment: In the latest version of Google Maps the downloaded maps for off-line use expire after 30 days unless updated.
This beats the purpose of using the off-line feature if the user is in an area where internet is not available or too slow/expensive to do the update - like an extended overseas holiday in a third-world country.
The 30 day period is too short. Google could be more generous.

Comment: @aussie43 Google generates profits when you go online; it will never be so generous.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps is not a good source for permanent offline maps, but it does have offline map capability

Pros

- Uses less memory
- will automatically download offline maps along your route in case you lose signal

Cons
 - offline maps self delete if unused for a time

---

Here WeGo is a good Android application for offline maps.

Pros

- You can download offline maps for your state/region, country, continent, or entire world.
- if you phone has aGPS, this application will work with or without cell service as long as you have downloaded the maps for your location and you can see the sky.
- Maps stay on your phone until you delete them.
- Gives you directions via walking, biking, public transport, lyft, driving, or ride share.

Cons

- You can not add nicknames to saved locations
- Uses more of phone memory (Map of the entire USA is just over 8GB)
- Managing saved places can be tedious.

---

For my personal use I usually use Waze for my day to day navigation needs, however when I go on long trips I use Here maps to download maps for regions I expect to be in, in case I lose cell signal or data connection. I only use google maps when Waze is having trouble with my request.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps got one of the worst offline map options out there, try something else instead. HERE or Sygic for example.

Comment: This could be a good answer if you explain how the OP can use these apps to solve their problem, and link to the apps you recommend. Just complaining that Google Maps isn't very good doesn't help anybody.